# How to escape javascript code from xml?

Tags: xml

I can't remember of find, but I know there were a way using something like `<[CODE` to write code inside the xml without have problems with the xml reserved symbols.. Does anyone knows?

Comment: See also: [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) and [Should I use “\]\]>” or “//\]\]>” for closing a CDATA section into xHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375217/should-i-use-or-for-closing-a-cdata-section-into-xhtml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, using `CDATA` - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Example:

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function matchwo(a,b)
{
if (a < b && a < 0) then
  {
  return 1;
  }
else
  {
  return 0;
  }
}
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Took the liberty of copying the example to the answer, in case the link dies/gets moved/etc.

Comment: they could make a easier to remember way.. Thanks!