# jQuery .each and .children not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, internet-explorer

I'm making an Instagram image slider feed, and it's working fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera, but it fails in all versions of IE. It doesn't even give me an error message, it just does nothing.

I needed to return the height of the images to the parent div to get the correct height for the background.

In IE the first image is loaded up and then nothing happens after that, it doesn't even return the height of the first image. I've searched around and think it might have something to do with .children() and .each() not working correctly in IE, but I'm not sure.

So is this the cause of a IE/jQuery compability issue? or is it something else? and is there an alternative way of doing this? (I have removed most of the Auth token for security purposes)

her is a jfiddle of the result: http://jsfiddle.net/5ACr9/embedded/result/

```
        (function($){
            $.fn.MySlider = function(interval) {
            var slides;
            var cnt;
            var amount;
            var j;

            function run() {
                // hiding previous image and showing next
                $(slides[j]).fadeOut(1000).removeClass("selected");
                j++;
                if (j >= amount) j = 0;
                $(slides[j]).fadeIn(1000).addClass("selected");
                // loop
                setTimeout(run, interval);
            }


            slides = $('#insta-slider').children();
            amount = slides.length;
            j=0;

            setTimeout(run, interval);
            };
        })(jQuery);

        // custom initialization
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            $('.smart_gallery').MySlider(5000);
              //gets the height of the first image and returns it to parent
            $( "#insta-slider" ).each(function() {
                        var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );
                    $.each( $this.children(), function() {
                        newHeight = $( this ).height();
                    });
                        $this.height( newHeight );
              });

            var tid = setTimeout(resize, 5000);

            function resize(){
                  //returns the height of each image after the first one
                  $( "#insta-slider" ).each(function() {
                            var newHeight2 = 0, $this = $( this );
                        $.each( $this.children(".selected"), function() {
                            newHeight2 = $( this ).height();
                        });
                            $this.height( newHeight2 );
                  });

              tid = setTimeout(resize, 5000);
           }

        });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While posting questions, try to show us only the relevant code and make a concise question. This question is really long and tiring.

Comment: Rest assured `children` and `each` work just fine in IE. Some versions of IE produce different DOM structures given the same HTML than Chrome/Firefox. (eg: TBODY element for tables).

Comment: Could you write a much smaller version of your JavaScript that demonstrates the issue, and include representative HTML with your question? Perhaps host an example that demonstrates the bug on jsfiddle?

Comment: OK, you've got a jsfiddle, great! Now, what's it supposed to do? For me (Firefox 24, Linux 32bit) it just shows a single image. That image is a link to instagram, There are two links below with `0` as their text which also open instagram. Otherewise, it seems to do nothing.

Comment: it's supposed to be a image carousel, but like in IE it only shows the first image. it never changes to the next image

Comment: What is your IE version you used to test this? Always good to mention which version.

Comment: It needs to support IE 9, 8 and 7. And I've tested it in those versions aswell.

Comment: So what's the question?  .each() works in IE....

Answer (score 0):

Check your `jquery version` if it is `gereater than` **1.9** then it will not work in **IE**

> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6,
>   7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in
>   JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility
>   often causes problems of its own. **But don’t worry, the jQuery team
>   still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8**. You can
>   (and should) continue to use jQuery 1.9 (and the upcoming 1.10) on web
>   sites that need to accommodate older browsers.

Read [jquery-2-0-released](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

Also check that you didn't use `console.log()` in your `javascript code` because it doesn't work in **IE**

You have use `CDATA` check that it is `properly ends` or read [Should I use "]]>" or "//]]>" for closing a CDATA section into xHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375217/should-i-use-or-for-closing-a-cdata-section-into-xhtml)

Comment: jquery version is 1.9 and CDATA is properly closed, but still nothing.

Comment: @Gustyninja In the fiddle I saw **JQMIGRATE: Logging is active** in **console** and I said in my `answer` that `console.log()` not works in **IE**, see the `migrate plugin` which you used.

Comment: oh ok, I don't have console.log() in my code, does it turn on automatically? is there anyway to force it off?

Comment: @Gustyninja This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this did nothing. So I don't think the console is the problem.

Comment: @RohanKumar To be exact, `console.log()` doesn't work when the console is not open in IE<10. This bug has been fixed in IE10+.